# PL SQL Developer allround automation updated to 9.0.6.1665 - error during starting up

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I've already updated my PL/SQL Developer (allround automation) to a new version (given above).

Now starting up the Tool I'm receiving the message (translated from German into English):

"Existing groups with same definition
This could led to problems".

One can continue but I'm courious to know the reason. Or should I expect additional problems?

Thx,
Peter

Comment: I would contact All Round Automations via their PL/SQL Developer Forums or by email: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem importing preferences.  Only one preference set should be enabled.  Perhaps the upgrade or installation process found multiple preferences and didn't know which one to enable.  I'm not sure what kind of problems it will cause.

For reference, the exact error message in the English version is "You have preferencesets with the same definition, this might not work correct.".

To fix this, click on Tools --> Preferences, then click on the button to open the Preference Set dialog:[image: Preferences Dialog]

In the Preference Set dialog, un-check "Enabled" for all but one of the preference sets.

[image: Preference Set dialog]